# Error: Code too large in R.java

Tags: java, android, xamarin, r.java-file, android-multidex

I'm developing a Xamarin android application which it'll have a long string.xml file (almost 20000 words).

When I compile the code, I receive an **error: Code too large**, due to a 64K byte-code size limit for a method.

The problem is that the method that's too big is the auto-generated string method inside R.java class (because the 20000 words are declared inside this method).

Using Visual Studio as a coding environment, I tried enabling MutiDex and ProGuard from the android settings menu, but still having this issue.

I'm also open to suggestions of different ways to import many strings instead of placing them inside the strings.xml file.

Any suggestion will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What are these words used for (i.e. Why do you need them as resources)?

Comment: The words will be used for the localization (I think this is how it's called - language changing based on the device language)

Comment: Your app has 20,000 unique words in one language?

Comment: Yes, only in one language. I also have for different languases the same amount, but since the resource IDs are the same, the string method size will be the same. There might be 2% values that can repeat but maily they're unique..

Comment: I tried with 25,000 strings in strings.xml file and it works fine...When I increase this number to 40,000, the error is "too many constants", not "code too large"...

Comment: Have you solved your issue? Could you please share your call stack and full debug logs?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT Thank you for your input. I tried a new project with 20000 unique strings, it worked indeed as you described. 
When importing that file into the problematic project it crashes with  when building, it does not deploy to export any logs. 

The more specific error is:

"Error  error: code too large
        public static int APP_STRING=0x7f07200f; R.java 3080"

where 3080 is the first line of String IDs in the auto-generated ResourceDesigner.cs file.

Do you have any suggestion about where should I look? Many thanks!